# Retrieve data from mysql php to Android

Tags: php, android, mysql

This is how normally we retrieve raw data from server with httppost or get.
This is one of the tutorial from google search
[Tutorial link](http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/02/10/android/android-connecting-to-mysql-using-php/)

1. use a HttpPost to get the data,
2. convert response to string parse
3. JSON data, and use it as you want

But what if i want retrieve data and together with related image into my **android apps**?What is the appropriate method to go for?

This is example of my **data**.

```
id    image_name  caption
 1      01.jpg     Abcd
```

and my image store in somewhere of **my server**.

```
upload/background_image/01.jpg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the image in base64 string in the server side, and retrieve it from the application.
then use the following to decode the base64 string into bitmap

```
public static String encodeTobase64(Bitmap image)
{
    Bitmap immagex=image;
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
    immagex.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
    String imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(b,Base64.DEFAULT);

   // Log.e("LOOK", imageEncoded);
    return imageEncoded;
}
public static Bitmap decodeBase64(String input) 
{
    byte[] decodedByte = Base64.decode(input, 0);
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByte, 0, decodedByte.length); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks , i think this is what i want , can this conversion done in php(client side)? what if i want to do caching in my apps, will it be difficult?

Comment: do you want to cache the images in the android device

Comment: Yes , I want to cache it , will it be a problem if i follow your way?

Comment: It depends on the size and count of the image.

Answer (score 2):

you can response them as url, and when you need the image content, issue another request.

or

you can read the image content, base64_encode it and response as string